# SMTP mail sent mail failed for production server(window8)

Tags: .net, outlook, iis-8

SMTP Exception Failure sending mail.SMTP Exception at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
I have attached the code below please find the code:
Using System.net.mail

```
try
    {

        Load_LDAP_Details();
        string subject = "Test SUbject";
        string body = "This is a test body";
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("abc@gmail.com", emailTo);
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Port = 25;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Host = "smtp.server.com";
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        client.Send(mail);
        client.EnableSsl = false;
        lblEmail.Text = "sent";

       client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;


    }
    catch (Exception ex) {

        string message = string.Format("Time: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));           

        message += string.Format("Message: {0}", ex.Message);

        message += string.Format("StackTrace: {0}", ex.StackTrace);

        message += string.Format("Source: {0}", ex.Source);

        // message += string.Format("TargetSite: {0}", ex.TargetSite.ToString());


        lblEmail.Text = message;

    }
```

Comment: Do you really think someone can help you with this little information? Please at least write a proper problem description with code.

Comment: Hi,I wrote simple mail sending code using netmail in c#.Its working fine in my local servrer.But when i sent mail from production server.mail not sent.

Comment: As per your suggestion i have a attached the code @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: Did you check you have proper credentials? You are using the windows authentication, it could a lack of privilege for the user used to run the application.  Try alternate solution like web credentials with username/password to nail down your issue.